# How to fill a column based on several other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': list('aaabdcde'),
        'B': list('smnipiuy'),
        'C': list('zzzqqwll')
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'mapcol': list('abpppozl')
    }
)

   A  B  C
0  a  s  z
1  a  m  z
2  a  n  z
3  b  i  q
4  d  p  q
5  c  i  w
6  d  u  l
7  e  y  l

  mapcol
0      a
1      b
2      p
3      p
4      p
5      o
6      z
7      l
```

Now I want to create an additional column in `df1` which should be filled with values coming from the columns `A`, `B` and `C` respectively, depending on whether their values can be found in `df2['mapcol']`. If the values in one row can be found in more than one column, they should be first used from `A`, then `B` and then `C`, so my expected outcome looks like this:

```
   A  B  C final
0  a  s  z     a  # <- values can be found in A and C, but A is preferred
1  a  m  z     a  # <- values can be found in A and C, but A is preferred
2  a  n  z     a  # <- values can be found in A and C, but A is preferred
3  b  i  q     b  # <- value can be found in A 
4  d  p  q     p  # <- value can be found in B
5  c  i  w   NaN  # none of the values can be mapped
6  d  u  l     l  # value can be found in C
7  e  y  l     l  # value can be found in C
```

A straightforward implementation could look like this (filling the column `final` iteratively using `fillna` in the preferred order):

```
preferred_order = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df1['final'] = np.nan

for col in preferred_order:
    df1['final'] = df1['final'].fillna(df1[col][df1[col].isin(df2['mapcol'])])
```

which gives the desired outcome.

Does anyone see a solution that avoids the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and `isin` on the full dataframe `df1` to mask the value not in the `df2`, then reorder with the `preferred_order` and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) along the column, keep the first column with `iloc`

```
preferred_order = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df1['final'] = (df1.where(df1.isin(df2['mapcol'].to_numpy()))
                   [preferred_order]
                   .bfill(axis=1)
                   .iloc[:, 0]
               )
print (df1)
   A  B  C final
0  a  s  z     a
1  a  m  z     a
2  a  n  z     a
3  b  i  q     b
4  d  p  q     p
5  c  i  w   NaN
6  d  u  l     l
7  e  y  l     l
```

Comment: Nice idea using `bfill` ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Use:**

```
order =  ['A', 'B', 'C'] # order of columns

d = df1[order].isin(df2['mapcol'].tolist()).loc[lambda x: x.any(axis=1)].idxmax(axis=1)
df1.loc[d.index, 'final'] = df1.lookup(d.index, d)
```

**Details:**

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and filter the rows using boolean masking with [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) along `axis=1` then use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along `axis=1` to get column names names associated with max values along `axis=1`.

```
print(d)
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
6    C
7    C
dtype: object
```

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to lookup the values in `df1` corresponding to the `index` and `columns` of `d` and assign this values to column `final`:

```
print(df1)
   A  B  C final
0  a  s  z     a
1  a  m  z     a
2  a  n  z     a
3  b  i  q     b
4  d  p  q     p
5  c  i  w   NaN
6  d  u  l     l
7  e  y  l     l
```